# Pinning multiple vertex groups in cloth physics

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am making a cloak for a character, and I want the cloth physics to become stronger for each loop starting from the bottom as they reach the top. So I'm trying to make the bottom loop of the cloak pinned at .9, the loop above that at .8, the loop above that at .7 and so on until the top part moves freely. 
Issue is, the cloth physics only allow you to pin one vertex group.

Anyone know of a fix around this?

Comment: ? Use different weights for the same group.

Comment: I tried using weightpaint, got something like this [weightgradient in one vertexgroup on cloth-plane](https://imgur.com/sgNBtmz). Not vertex paint, but weight paint. I set values for the top and bottom line and then used smooth to get the gradient. Though the stiffness had to be dialed down to get the effect.

Comment: You can assign the wanted values directly either weight painting or assigning the vertex weight in the property panel.

Comment: @lemon while i used weight painting, where exactly/which "property panel" do you mean?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html and a picture for 2.8 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY6Hf.jpg

Comment: In the clothing physics you are only allowed to pin and adjust the stiffness to one vertex group. I do not follow what you mean by just "use different weights."

Comment: If you look at the picture i attached, you see only one vertex group but that group has a gradient of weighting on it. I used Weight Paint mode for that.

Comment: I just looked at it. The original response was for lemon. I will try to do that.

Comment: You want 0.9 0.8 etc if I understand well. So assign these values to the wanted vertices. Look at this part of the doc: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html#assigning-vertices-to-a-group

Comment: While you can assign the weights with different values in one group, i believe the weight paint is still more intuitive. That said if it's just a simple gradient, you may just go line by line and increase the value to then click assign. The documentation is a bit confusing though, as it shows multiple vertex groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways, while both do the same for your situation i believe the direct setting of values may be faster, but painting weights can be more intuitive and should be better for detailed weighting in special situations.

1. Go in "Weight Paint" mode (for visual feedback, as it allows to see what happens by displaying the colors as you set the values)
2. Select all the vertices that you want to use in the pin-group
3. Create a Vertex Group and assign all the vertices to it by pressing the assign button.
4. Now select each line and set the value that line of vertices should have in the "Weight" Field under the "Assign" button.
5. In the documentation it says that "Assign" is additive, but that does not mean the weight value will be added, it just means the vertices will be added to the group if they are not already in it.
6. After all lines of vertices are set, you should have a gradient showing the weights going from top to bottom.
7. In the cloth panel, under shape, you will have to adjust the "Stiffness" to make the weighting show more or less effect (i used 0.01 in the example).

Here a simple visualisation of the steps and a final cloth sim result:

[image]

Update (thanks for pointing it out @atomicbezierslinger):

[image]

Important to note though is that if you use a tablet, and have <kbd>MMB</kbd> emulation on, you won't be able to use the function without either changing the keymap or deactivating the emulation.

Comment: Is there also a gradient tool with some particular keystroke?

Comment: Not that i know of, but in the case of this topic it was a simple gradient that was asked for even if not named directly, the slow decreasing or increasing of weight for the loops from top to bottom results in a gradient after all.

Comment: I just looked it up .. Alt Left Mouse.  You could put in another picture. Info Window ...... bpy.ops.paint.weight_gradient(type='LINEAR', xstart=829, xend=1208, ystart=327, yend=188)

Comment: Blender Preferences ... Keymap..  Search Gradient.

Comment: I am not using a tablet at the moment.  However with F3 search [gradient] it puts Blender in the correct mode for one click to ... drag without the alt key.  I may not understand your statement fully.  Life goes on.  We do not have to alt drag the topic out.