# How can I control multiple points of a cloth sim?

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I'm following a tutorial for a crate design, but I wanted to add some extra flair to it. I thought it would be cool to animate a ribbon of wires as it slides open. It's almost done, but I can't figure out the last bit.

[image: Animated Wire Ribbon]

As you can see, the ribbon isn't pinned down on the opposite end, so it just slowly slides out of place. I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169796/pinning-multiple-vertex-groups-in-cloth-physics) on in another post, but I couldn't figure out how to apply those techniques to my test scene. I'm still pretty new to Blender, so I'd very much appreciate any help/advice. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: if you don't care about not doing it with cloth simulation, you could easily do it with a Curve modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of constraints you could hook the left extremity to an empty and add the vertices of the opposite extremity to the pin group. Put the *Hook* modifier above the *Cloth* modifier. In the *Physics* properties, increase the *Quality Steps* up to 20 to make it work correctly. You don't tell about what's supposed to happen after the last picture of your gif, does the extremity on the right stay still?

[image]

[image]

Even simpler, you could give up cloth simulation and use a *Curve* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, I don't understand how to hook up the left-side verts to the empty while keeping the right-side verts pinned down. I've tried finding videos and reading about it, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for or put the pieces together.

As for what's supposed to happen after the final frame of my gif, the goal is for it to just stop, then reverse with the lid slides back into a closed position. The curve modifier method is waaaaay simpler and I would consider using it, but I really want to understand how to control the verts.

Comment: select the left vertices and press Ctrl H to hook to new object, it will automatically create the empty, don't use any constraint for the belt, just add the vertices on the right to the pin group, and it should work, I'll add the blend file if necessary. Edit: oh and don't forget to put the Hook modifier above the Cloth modifier!

Comment: Wow...that is so fast and easy. Thank you!